# Avoid the count of NULL values in mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

Want to only count the rows that are set and avoid the rows that are not set

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS total_memebers, 
  COUNT(case member_feesdue when null then 1 else 0 end) AS total_feesdue 
FROM sdg_members
```

Answer (score 2):

COUNT never counts NULLs. SELECT COUNT(col) FROM tbl is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to count `total_feesdue` where it equals to 1?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS total_memebers, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sdg_members WHERE sdg_members = 1) AS total_feesdue 
FROM sdg_members
```

Comment: I want to count only those rows from the column which has values and avoid the rows in which this column is empty